# How can I merge two data frames when I need to combine the information of a row to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I have two data frames, the first one contains statistics for a product and the second one is an empty data frame I created. I need to take the data from the first dataframe and insert it into the second. I only know how to join data from columns and rows, is there a way for me to do this?

```
product = 'PRDQM0011122TR131'
prod_results = pm.summary(trace_dict_prodlevel[product])
prod_results

          | mean     | sd                 |
          | -------- | --------           |
Slope     | -0.012   | -0.012            |
 Intercept| 0.906    | 0.356              |

prod_results1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['product', 'slope_mean', 'slope_sd', 'int_mean', 'int_sd'])
prod_results1

| product | slope_mean | slope_sd  |int_mean |int_sd|
|---------|------------|-----------|---------|------|
```

the desired output would be this:

| product         | slope_mean | slope_sd  |int_mean |int_sd|

|PRDQM0011122TR131|-0.012      |-0.012     |0.906    |0.356 |

I thought pd.concat or pd.join would work but I don't know how to apply them to this case.

Comment: can you provide reproducible inputs (as code)?

Comment: @mozway I don't get what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could input data directly from your `prod_results` dataframe to your `prod_results1` dataframe. This works and given the case is simple, using something like `melt` might be too much.

Since you do not provide code to reproduce your data, this is my guess for working code:

```py
prod_results1['product'] = product
prod_results1['slope_mean'] = prod_results.loc[prod_results.index=='Slope', 'mean']
prod_results1['slope_sd'] = prod_results.loc[prod_results.index=='Slope', 'sd']
prod_results1['int_mean'] = prod_results.loc[prod_results.index=='Intercept', 'mean']
prod_results1['int_sd'] = prod_results.loc[prod_results.index=='Intercept', 'sd']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you are asking. You can run this code as loop as well. Loop should only update the `product` and `df`. So, the loop should look like the following:

```
for product in products:
    df= pm.summary(trace_dict_prodlevel[product])
```

Followed by rest of my below code.

```
df1 = df.melt(value_vars = ['slope', 'intercept'], var_name = 'stat', value_name = 'val' )
mapping = {
    0: "slope_mean",
    1: "slope_sd",
    2: "int_mean",
    3: "int_sd"
}

# Apply the mapping to the 'stat' column
df1["stat"] = df1.index.map(mapping)
df1 = df1.set_index('stat').T
df1['product'] = 'prod1'
prod_results1 = pd.concat([prod_results1, df1], axis = 0)

print(prod_results1)

product  slope_mean  slope_sd  int_mean  int_sd
val   prod1      -0.012     0.906    -0.012   0.356
```